# MySQL: When updating, ignore empty strings

Tags: mysql

I know how to do this using PHP, but I was wondering if MySQL provides for a simpler solution.

```
UPDATE users SET fname = 'badooka', lname = '' WHERE user_id='322';
```

If a value is empty (lname, in this particular case), how do I ignore it instead of overwriting the original with an empty string?

Comment: I would agree with Myles response 'UPDATE users SET fname = 'badooka', lname = '' WHERE user_id='322' AND lname != '';' by doing so you are just ignoring empty value(lname, in this case) instead of overwriting the original with an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `UPDATE users SET fname = 'badooka', lname = '' WHERE user_id='322' AND lname != '';` Or do you mean have the database just not update that field that is empty? If the latter then no, there's not a simpler way, but the performance hit is negligible to update an additional field in a row that you are already updating.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE users 
SET fname = IF(CHAR_LENGTH('badooka'),'badooka',fname), lname = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(''),'',lname) 
WHERE user_id='322';
```

That's the basic idea. If CHAR_LENGTH() returns 0, it'll use the original values.

Answer (score 1):

The COALESCE operator will select the first non-null value of its arguments

so if you want to only update lname when lname is not empty, I might do something like this

```
UPDATE users SET fname = 'badooka', COALESCE( lname, SELECT lname FROM users where user_id='322' ) where user_id='322'
```

is that what you meant? this might be a bit of a performance hit if you're doing a lot, someone else know a better way?

Comment: Ok now that an answer has been accepted, I can see that obviously I misinterpreted the question as not overwriting a non-null with a null, where the asker meant not overwriting a null with a non-null...ah well if people come looking I still think this would be the answer if the case was reversed...

Comment: I would agree, sorry about the confusion